# Вёрстка картинок на Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Как сверстать на Bootstrap такую "композицию" из картинок?

[image: картинка]

С сеткой я разобрался вроде как мне организовать её, а вот изображения как правильно вставляются?
Если через `<img>` , то картинка вылазит за края сетки при уменьшении размера экрана, не адаптивненько выходит.
А если картинку грузить в `<div>` и `<div>` поставить `background-size:contain`
, то не семантично уже, картинки ж желательно в `<img>` пихать?

```css
.class1{background: url() no-repeat; width: 576px; height: 385px; float:left; margin:5px}
.class1:hover{background: url() no-repeat;}

.class2{background: url() no-repeat; width: 274px; height: 183px; float:left; margin:5px}
.class2:hover{background: url() no-repeat; }

.class3{background: url() no-repeat; width: 274px; height: 183px; float:left; margin:5px}
.class3:hover{background: url() no-repeat;}

.class4{background: url() no-repeat;  width: 274px; height: 183px; float:left; margin:5px}
.class4:hover{background: url() no-repeat; }

.class5{background: url() no-repeat; width: 274px; height: 183px; float:left; margin:5px}
.class5:hover{background: url() no-repeat; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 ">    
 <img class="class1">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 ">
 <img class="class2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2">
 <img class="class3">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 ">
 <img class="class4">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2 ">
 <img class="class5">
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: укажите Ваш код в тексте вопроса.

Comment: простите что за код?

Comment: ваш код, вашу верстку, то как Вы пытались самостоятельно решить задачу.

Comment: сорри, туплю, давно за компом уже сижу просто, щас...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L7fvmmzk/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.b-pict {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 66.79%;
  position: relative;
}

.b-pict > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.b-pict-date,
.b-pict-caption {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.b-pict-date {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.b-pict-caption {
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" />
        <span class="b-pict-date">text date</span>
        <h4 class="b-pict-caption">title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b-pict">
            <img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" />
            <span class="b-pict-date">text date</span>
            <h4 class="b-pict-caption">title</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b-pict">
            <img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" />
            <span class="b-pict-date">text date</span>
            <h4 class="b-pict-caption">title</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b-pict">
            <img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" />
            <span class="b-pict-date">text date</span>
            <h4 class="b-pict-caption">title</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="b-pict">
            <img src="http://authentic-scandinavia.com/system/images/tours/photos/155/thumbnail.jpg?1370424008" alt="" />
            <span class="b-pict-date">text date</span>
            <h4 class="b-pict-caption">title</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="тут_ваш_путь_к_фото" class="img-responsive text-center">
```

bootstrap-класс .img-responsive - делает изображение адаптивным

bootstrap-класс .text-center - фото посередине!

https://itchief.ru/lessons/bootstrap-3/34-bootstrap-3-images